# TFS2015 new work item widget

Tags: tfs-2015

I'm looking for a way to change the default work item type from the "New work item" widget.

Currently the default value is Bug and I'd like to change it to Feature.

I'm using TFS2015.2 on-premise.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible, either with TFS on-prem, or with VSTS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's impossible for now. First, since there are no such settings on the web portal directly.

Moreover, the workitem types seems to be sorted in alphabetical order. So, "*Bug*" should be the default value.

[image]

It's also different with the order in Team Explorer.

[image]